# How do I use a string variable in the printf() function in c?

Tags: c

I am running the following c program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char str1;
    printf("What is your name? ");
    scanf("%s.", str1);
    printf("Hi there %s.", str1);
    return 0;
}
```

But this what it returns:

```
What is your name? Varun
Hi there (null).
```

Why does it say `(null)`? Please answer.

Comment: Well, `str1` is only one-character and cannot represent a string (other than empty-string). Say `char str1[128];` try again with `if (scanf("%127s", str1) != 1) { return 1; }` And see [10 Commandments for C Programmers - No. 6](http://www.seebs.net/c/10com.html)

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple mistakes here:

1. You use %s for a char variable.
2. You're not passing a pointer to `scanf` function. You're just passing a garbage value.

You introduced an undefined behavior. And you should have some compile-warnings that tells you that you have mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

char str1;  you have space for only 1 char , that's not much , try replacing with char str1[30]; and try again.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char str1[1000];   // <-- here are the changes
    printf("What is your name? ");
    scanf("%s.", str1);
    printf("Hi there %s.", str1);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To use strings in c, you need to create a char array with a specific size

```
char arr[1000]; // array of size 1000, it can contain a string of 1000 letters
```

then to fetch the string you have to use

```
scanf("%s", arr);
```

then to print it back use

```
printf("%s", arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <malloc.h>
int main() {
    char *str;
    str = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * 10);
    printf("What is your name?");
    scanf("%s", str);
    printf("Hi there %s.", str);
    return 0;
}
```

I think you should do like this, you should understand char and string.

Comment: That code is not advisable: If the number of characters entered is greater than 9, that will cause undefined behaviour. Also, there is no such thing as `<malloc.h>` in standard C. `malloc` function is declared in the `<stdlib.h>`.